# AJAX Request Running Twice on Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, email-validation

I am doing a Validation for email input

```
$("#email").on("input",function() 
{
    email = $(this).val();
     const regex_1 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;

     const regex_2 = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,10})+$/;

var re1 = new RegExp(regex_1);   
var re2 = new RegExp(regex_2);   

     if(re1.test(email)===true && re2.test(email)===true)
     {
         e.preventDefault();

         $.ajax({  
                url:"Validate.php",  
                method:"POST", 

                data:'type=check_email&email='+email,  

                success:function(data)
                {  

            if(data == 'FAIL')
            {
                $("#email").addClass("is-invalid");
                $("#email").removeClass("is-valid");
                $("#email").focus();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#email").addClass("is-valid");
                $("#email").removeClass("is-invalid");
            }
                }  
           });  
     }
     else
     {
           $("#email").addClass("is-invalid");
           $("#email").removeClass("is-valid");
       $("#email").focus();
     }
        $("#email").removeClass("is-invalid");
        $("#email").removeClass("is-valid"); 
  });
```

So my issue is that when the validation through RegEx passes , the AJAX Call is made twice whereas the result from the first **success:function(data)** itself returns **SUCCESS**.

Two successive queries for the same instance will increase load on the server unnecessarily.

I personally think my bind is wrong here or that I haven't used e.preventDefault();

But I tried using **input focus change keyup** (individually as well as multiple binds) but nothing worked, the query still runs twice.

The concept here is that only when the RegEx test returns **true** then only the ajax is required to run (just once). Why is it running twice here ?

> **Required : The email(string) should pass both the RegEx tests**

Answer (score 2):

The event parameter `e` in the code is missing.

```
$("#email").on("input",function(e)
    ...
    ...
    e.preventDefault();
```

**Edit:**

To prevent multiple event firing from the handler, you can `return false;` From JQuery docs:

> Returning false from an event handler will automatically call
>   event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault().

In cases where the event is *bound* more than once, ensure only one handler is available by using `off()`. e.g.

```
$("#email").off('input').on("input",function(e) {
   ...
```

Comment: Should preventDefault be used just before the AJAX call inside the if(regex.test(str)===true) or just before initiating the function code?

Comment: Also, you don't need to compare to `true`. It's like saying `if(true === true)`. Just do `if(regex.test(str))`, etc.

Comment: @suspectus It is not working as expected. Still the AJAX call is happening twice